# Sobel Filter (OpenMP implementation)

Tags: c, openmp, xeon-phi, sobel, knights-landing

I am trying to implement a parallelized + vectorized version of Sobel Filter in C with OpenMP pragmas for the paralleization and #pragma simd for vectorization. My input is a .pgm image of 1024 by 1024. I am compiling this using Intel Compiler on a Xeon Knights Landing processor using the following command:

```
icc -qopenmp -O3 -qopt-report3 xeon.c -o xeon
```

So problems I am facing with the code in general are:

a) when do I parallelize and when do I vectorize. I have a nested for loop made up of four for loops -> should I parallelize or vectorize this piece of code

b) My 'min' and 'max' values are wrong. They are both shared variables and hence prone to race conditions, so I have added a #pragma omp critical around them. However, the values printed out for these two variables are still wrong and I have no idea why. I have even added a barrier before the print statement to make sure all threads pass through that critical section before the min and max values get printed out

c) the #pragma omp critical is making my program very very slow. In fact the execution time is even longer than the sequential runtime. Is there any way to avoid it?

**mypgm.h**

```
/* pgm file IO headerfile ------ mypgm.h */

/* Constant declaration */


#define MAX_IMAGEWIDTH  1024
#define MAX_IMAGEHEIGHT  1024
#define MAX_BRIGHTNESS  255 /* Maximum gray level */
#define GRAYLEVEL       256 /* No. of gray levels */
#define MAX_FILENAME    256 /* Filename length limit */
#define MAX_BUFFERSIZE  256

/* Global constant declaration */
/* Image storage arrays */
float image1[MAX_IMAGEWIDTH][MAX_IMAGEHEIGHT] __attribute__((aligned(64))),
image2[MAX_IMAGEWIDTH][MAX_IMAGEHEIGHT] __attribute__((aligned(64)));
int x_size1, y_size1, /* width & height of image1*/
x_size2, y_size2; /* width & height of image2 */

/* Prototype declaration of functions */
void load_image_data( ); /* image input */
void save_image_data( ); /* image output*/
void load_image_file(char *); /* image input */
void save_image_file(char *); /* image output*/


/* Main body of functions */

void load_image_data( )
/* Input of header & body information of pgm file */
/* for image1[ ][ ]，x_size1，y_size1 */
{
  char file_name[MAX_FILENAME];
  char buffer[MAX_BUFFERSIZE];
  FILE *fp; /* File pointer */
  int max_gray; /* Maximum gray level */
  int x, y; /* Loop variable */

  /* Input file open */
  printf("\n-----------------------------------------------------\n");
  printf("Monochromatic image file input routine \n");
  printf("-----------------------------------------------------\n\n");
  printf("     Only pgm binary file is acceptable\n\n");
  printf("Name of input image file? (*.pgm) : ");
  scanf("%s", file_name);
  fp = fopen(file_name, "rb");
  if (NULL == fp) {
    printf("     The file doesn't exist!\n\n");
    exit(1);
  }
  /* Check of file-type ---P5 */
  fgets(buffer, MAX_BUFFERSIZE, fp);
  if (buffer[0] != 'P' || buffer[1] != '5') {
     printf("     Mistaken file format, not P5!\n\n");
     exit(1);
  }
  /* input of x_size1, y_size1 */
  x_size1 = 0;
  y_size1 = 0;
  while (x_size1 == 0 || y_size1 == 0) {
    fgets(buffer, MAX_BUFFERSIZE, fp);
    if (buffer[0] != '#') {
      sscanf(buffer, "%d %d", &x_size1, &y_size1);
    }
  }
  /* input of max_gray */
  max_gray = 0;
  while (max_gray == 0) {
  fgets(buffer, MAX_BUFFERSIZE, fp);
  if (buffer[0] != '#') {
    sscanf(buffer, "%d", &max_gray);
  }
}
  /* Display of parameters */
  printf("\n     Image width = %d, Image height = %d\n", x_size1, y_size1);
  printf("     Maximum gray level = %d\n\n",max_gray);
  if (x_size1 > MAX_IMAGEWIDTH || y_size1 > MAX_IMAGEHEIGHT) {
     printf("     Image size exceeds %d x %d\n\n", 
      MAX_IMAGEWIDTH, MAX_IMAGEHEIGHT);
     printf("     Please use smaller images!\n\n");
     exit(1);
  }
  if (max_gray != MAX_BRIGHTNESS) {
  printf("     Invalid value of maximum gray level!\n\n");
  exit(1);
}
/* Input of image data*/
#pragma simd
for (y = 0; y < y_size1; y++) {
  #pragma simd
  for (x = 0; x < x_size1; x++) {
     image1[y][x] = (unsigned char)fgetc(fp);
  }
}
printf("-----Image data input OK-----\n\n");
printf("-----------------------------------------------------\n\n");
fclose(fp);
}

void save_image_data( )
/* Output of image2[ ][ ], x_size2, y_size2 in pgm format*/

{
  char file_name[MAX_FILENAME];
  FILE *fp; /* File pointer */
  int x, y; /* Loop variable */

  /* Output file open */
  printf("-----------------------------------------------------\n");
  printf("Monochromatic image file output routine\n");
  printf("-----------------------------------------------------\n\n");
  printf("Name of output image file? (*.pgm) : ");
  scanf("%s",file_name);
  fp = fopen(file_name, "wb");
  /* output of pgm file header information */
  fputs("P5\n", fp);
  fputs("# Created by Image Processing\n", fp);
  fprintf(fp, "%d %d\n", x_size2, y_size2);
  fprintf(fp, "%d\n", MAX_BRIGHTNESS);
  /* Output of image data */
 #pragma simd
  for (y = 0; y < y_size2; y++) {
    #pragma simd
    for (x = 0; x < x_size2; x++) {
       fputc(image2[y][x], fp);
     }
   }
   printf("\n-----Image data output OK-----\n\n");
   printf("-----------------------------------------------------\n\n");
   fclose(fp);
}

void load_image_file(char *filename)
/* Input of header & body information of pgm file */
/* for image1[ ][ ]，x_size1，y_size1 */
{
   char buffer[MAX_BUFFERSIZE];
   FILE *fp; /* File pointer */
   int max_gray; /* Maximum gray level */
   int x, y; /* Loop variable */

   /* Input file open */
   fp = fopen(filename, "rb");
   if (NULL == fp) {
     printf("     The file doesn't exist!\n\n");
     exit(1);
   }
   /* Check of file-type ---P5 */
   fgets(buffer, MAX_BUFFERSIZE, fp);
   if (buffer[0] != 'P' || buffer[1] != '5') {
     printf("     Mistaken file format, not P5!\n\n");
     exit(1);
   }
   /* input of x_size1, y_size1 */
   x_size1 = 0;
   y_size1 = 0;
   while (x_size1 == 0 || y_size1 == 0) {
     fgets(buffer, MAX_BUFFERSIZE, fp);
     if (buffer[0] != '#') {
       sscanf(buffer, "%d %d", &x_size1, &y_size1);
     }
   }
   /* input of max_gray */
   max_gray = 0;
   while (max_gray == 0) {
     fgets(buffer, MAX_BUFFERSIZE, fp);
     if (buffer[0] != '#') {
        sscanf(buffer, "%d", &max_gray);
     }
   }
   if (x_size1 > MAX_IMAGEWIDTH || y_size1 > MAX_IMAGEHEIGHT) {
     printf("     Image size exceeds %d x %d\n\n", 
        MAX_IMAGEWIDTH, MAX_IMAGEHEIGHT);
     printf("     Please use smaller images!\n\n");
     exit(1);
   }
   if (max_gray != MAX_BRIGHTNESS) {
     printf("     Invalid value of maximum gray level!\n\n");
     exit(1);
   }
   /* Input of image data*/
  #pragma simd
  for (y = 0; y < y_size1; y++) {
    #pragma simd
    for (x = 0; x < x_size1; x++) {
       image1[y][x] = (float)fgetc(fp);
     }
  }
  fclose(fp);
}

void save_image_file(char *filename)
/* Output of image2[ ][ ], x_size2, y_size2 */ 
/* into pgm file with header & body information */
{
  FILE *fp; /* File pointer */
  int x, y; /* Loop variable */

  fp = fopen(filename, "wb");
  /* output of pgm file header information */
  fputs("P5\n", fp);
  fputs("# Created by Image Processing\n", fp);
  fprintf(fp, "%d %d\n", x_size2, y_size2);
  fprintf(fp, "%d\n", MAX_BRIGHTNESS);
  /* Output of image data */
 #pragma simd
  for (y = 0; y < y_size2; y++) {
    #pragma simd
    for (x = 0; x < x_size2; x++) {
      fputc(image2[y][x], fp);
    }
  }
  fclose(fp);
}
```

**xeon.c**

```
/* sobel.c */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <float.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <omp.h>
#include "mypgm.h"



void sobel_filtering( )
     /* Spatial filtering of image data */
     /* Sobel filter (horizontal differentiation */
     /* Input: image1[y][x] ---- Outout: image2[y][x] */
{
  /* Definition of Sobel filter in horizontal direction */
  float weight[3][3] __attribute__((aligned(64)))= {{ -1,  0,  1 },
              { -2,  0,  2 },
              { -1,  0,  1 }};
  float pixel_value;
  float min, max;
  int x, y, i, j;  /* Loop variable */

  /* Maximum values calculation after filtering*/
  printf("Now, filtering of input image is performed\n\n");


  min = DBL_MAX;
  max = -DBL_MAX;
  #pragma omp parallel shared(image2,weight,image1,min,max) private(y,x,j,i)
  {
    #pragma omp for collapse(2)

    for (y=0;y<y_size1;y++)  {
       for (x=0;x<x_size1;x++)  {
          image2[y][x]=0;
       }
    }
    #pragma omp for collapse(2) reduction(+:pixel_value)

    for (y = 1; y < y_size1 - 1; y++) {
      //#pragma simd
      for (x = 1; x < x_size1 - 1; x++) {
        pixel_value = 0.0;
        #pragma simd
        //#pragma omp for collapse(2)
        for (j = -1; j <= 1; j++) {
          #pragma simd
          for (i = -1; i <= 1; i++) {
             pixel_value += weight[j + 1][i + 1] * image1[y + j][x + i];
          }
        }
        image2[y][x] = (float)pixel_value;
        #pragma omp critical
       { 
          if (pixel_value < min) 
             min = pixel_value;
          if (pixel_value > max)
             max = pixel_value;
       } 
   }
 }
 #pragma omp barrier
 #pragma omp single
 {
   if ((int)(max - min) == 0) {
    printf("Nothing exists!!!\n\n");
    exit(1);
   }
  printf("%f\n",min);
  printf("%f\n",max);
 }

  /* Generation of image2 after linear transformtion */

  #pragma omp for private(x) collapse(2)
     //#pragma simd
     for (y=1;y<y_size1-1;y++)  {
       //#pragma simd
       for (x=1;x<x_size1-1;x++)  {
         image2[y][x] = MAX_BRIGHTNESS * (image2[y][x] - min) / (max - min);
       }
     }
 } // ends the parallel section
} //end of sobel filtering function

int main( )
{
  load_image_data( );   /* Input of image1 */ 
  clock_t begin=clock();
  sobel_filtering( );   /* Sobel filter is applied to image1 */
  clock_t end=clock();
  double time_spent = (double)(end-begin)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
  printf("\n\nTiming result of multiplication of matrix-vector: %f\n",time_spent);
  save_image_data( );   /* Output of image2 */
  return 0;
}
```

Thank you

Comment: I can post the vectorization report too if that helps: many of the loops are being vectorized which is why I want to use #pragma simd to force it: is that a good practice?

Comment: I only had a quick look, but you appear to be doing everything in `float` which seems odd if you are trying to use SIMD and optimise the filtration?

Comment: Did you check the performance of your collapse clauses?  #pragma simd would make no difference unless a difference shows in opt-report.

Comment: You probably need outer loop parallel, maybe 1 thread per core, and inner loop vectorized.  You will need to test various numbers of threads according to kmp_hw_subset.

Comment: 2) How exactly "wrong"? 3) Use `reduction(min:min)`. Also: what's the point of `reduction(+:pixel_value)` if `pixel_value` is not used outside and always reset within the loop? Generally: defining variables as locally as possible makes code more easy to reason about with OpenMP.